# How to add a button in the navigation bar in my android application?

Tags: java, android

In my application (only for my application), I want to add a button to the navigation system bar

[image]

How I can do that in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do anything there. Not to mention some devices will not show this bar at all if they got hardware buttons.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Maybe try to add a fragment that will be exactly above it.

Some phones don't even have that buttons on screen.

Answer (score 2):

*firstly check mobile or tab has soft buttons if has then  make full screen by programaticaly after that  create custum button bar like tab bar at bottom and put buttons as you like thats better if u dont have any other idea*

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Comment: you also can get all button action or controls  in activity

Comment: I m newbie in Android. Could you please detail your answer. Could you please explain how to add this custum button bar like tab bar at bottom.

Comment: Does the custum button bar like tab bar detect the ontouch events even if it's behind the navigation bar?